# Data masking of CSV files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, masking

My company works in germany and we have some rules to handle data.

I have CSV files in a bucket. And those files have some PII (Publicly Identifiable Information) and non-PII data too. I want to mask the PII data and save it in the same bucket. And I would like to unmask it when doing final reporting.

Comment: Look at the new [Amazon S3 Object Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/) feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it's much harder in AWS to set permissions at the folder level inside a bucket than to set the permissions at a bucket level.  Since buckets are basically free, I would recommend having separate buckets for PII and masked-PII data.

A better solution might be to expose the masked PII data using an Athena View.  Build the view with SQL that masks the PII data and expose that masked view to your users.  Then you won't need to maintain two copies of the data, ETL jobs to mask the data, or bucket permissions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html

Comment: Can you please give some more insights on what should I follow and things I should take care of ..

Comment: Generally?  Encrypt everything.  Enable "block all public access".  Check out the well architected framework and audit security regularly.

Answer (score 0):

One option is for you to have SNS mask the sensitive data for you, as you move the data from one S3 folder to another S3 folder. Here's the data flow that I have in mind: S3 (source) >> SNS >> Kinesis Firehose >> S3 (destination).

SNS introduced a data protection feature, in 2022, which can detect sensitive data flowing through SNS topics, then either block, mask, or redact the sensitive data.

For more information: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-message-data-protection-for-amazon-sns/